# How to select stylistic set for a font in Krita?

Tags: fonts, krita

I have a font with few stylistic sets. How do I select a specific stylistic set of it in Krita? I have found some [information](https://www.typography.com/faq/157) about it only for Adobe InDesign and Illustrator, but it seems I cannot find anything regarding Krita. Is it possible to do it in Krita?

Comment: You should check the Krita documentation to see what the software is capable of. Krita is nothing like these Adobe products, so information on these is not useful. The text options are all documented here: https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/text.html?highlight=text%20tool - it's pretty basic to be honest. Krita is a drawing tool, not page layout software. If you are looking for Open Source page layout software like InDesign, check out Scribus.

Comment: Also note if you are looking for software like Illustrator, the Open Source equivalent is Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks. I know what Krita is, I just need to write some text on an image and it happens that font I need to use has stylistic set which I need. I provided link to how to do it in InDesign or Illustrator to be more clear what I want. Not that I need InDesigns or Illustrators functionalities. Well, I guess if it is so basic as documentation says, what I need is impossible to do.

Comment: Yes,  it is as basic as the documentation says. There may be a work around though, such as typing it in another application, then exporting it in a format that Krita can import - such as a raster format, or SVG.